# идентичность выражений

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template < class Tp, class C = std::list<Tp>, size_t Tag = 5 >
class accountant {};

class  D1 : accountant<double> {};
class  D2 : accountant<double, void, void> {};
```

Хотелось бы узнать как будут отличаться  производные классы, если эти два выражения не идентичны? Или все таки они идентичны?..

По причине того, что я неправильно задал интересующий мне вопрос, добавлю ниже

класс `D2`  не компилируется, а вот это:

```
class It : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int, void, void, void>{};
```

компилируется.
И вот это тоже:

```
class It : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int> {};
```

В чем причина? И в чем разница между первым определением  класса It  и вторым?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотелось бы понять, как вы собираетесь скомпилировать

```
class  D2 : accountant<double, void, void> {};
```

подставляя `void` вместо *значения*? :)

Но в любом случае они будут различны. Как будут различны классы

```
class D1: public Base {};
class D2: public Base {};
```

А вот, скажем,

```
accountant<double>
```

и

```
accountant<double,std::list<double>,5>
```

эти будут [идентичными](https://ideone.com/oswiyS).

**Update**

Вот как `iterator` определен в VC++2017:

```
template<class _Category,
    class _Ty,
    class _Diff = ptrdiff_t,
    class _Pointer = _Ty *,
    class _Reference = _Ty&>
    struct _CXX17_DEPRECATE_ITERATOR_BASE_CLASS iterator
    {   // base type for iterator classes
    using iterator_category = _Category;
    using value_type = _Ty;
    using difference_type = _Diff;
    using pointer = _Pointer;
    using reference = _Reference;
    };
```

Видно, что три последние параметра шаблона - просто типы, со значениями по умолчанию. `void` - тоже просто тип... так что его можно использовать в качестве аргументов шаблона. Если не использовать ничего - то этими типами в вашем варианте (для `int`) будут `ptrdiff_t`, `int*` и `int&`.

Оба варианта компилируются - пока вы не попытаетесь использовать, скажем, псевдоним `pointer` для определения переменной или что-нибудь в этом роде, где `void` использовать категорически нельзя.

Comment: вы правы, я просто неправильно задал вопрос.  Классы конечно будут различны...

Comment: Просто нужно было спросить, что означает вместо аргументов по умолчанию  void, потому что где то я читал такое, и если не ошибаюсь, то в книге Страуструпа. Но то же самое не получается компилировать, потому и возник вопрос

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: "Вместо аргументов по умолчанию void"? Но void в данном случае - это просто имя типа void, такое же, как и имя любого другого типа. Никакого специального смысла оно не имеет.

Comment: @AnT, если честно, то не совсем понел, почему D2 не компилируется, а вот  с  It ом нет проблем?  Уверен, вы сможете ответить подробнее

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Последний параметр вашего шаблона accountant должен быть целым числом, а не типом. Передавать void туда, где ожидается 1, 2 или 42 - бессмысленно.

Comment: @Harry, так как я после вашего ответа внес  добавление в вопросе, прошу смотрите еще раз

Comment: @AnT, вот  где раки зимуют...  Понел, спасибо!

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Harry,  Da, спасибо, все  понятно